# OpenGL sRGB framebuffer oddity

Tags: opengl, nvidia, glfw

I'm using GLFW3 to create a context and I've noticed that the `GLFW_SRGB_CAPABLE` property seems to have no effect. Regardless of what I set it to, I always get sRGB conversion when `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB` is enabled. My understanding is that when `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB` is enabled, you get sRGB conversion only if the framebuffer is an sRGB format. To add to the confusion, if I check the `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_COLOR_ENCODING` I get `GL_LINEAR` regardless of what I set `GLFW_SRGB_CAPABLE` to. This doesn't appear to be an issue with GLFW. I created a window and context manually and was sure to set `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB_CAPABLE_ARB` to true.

I'm using a Nvidia GTX 760 with the 340.76 drivers. I'm checking the format like this:

```
glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameteriv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_FRONT_LEFT, GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_COLOR_ENCODING, &enc);
```

This should return `GL_SRGB`, should it not? If it is applying sRGB correction regardless of what `WGL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB_CAPABLE_ARB` is set to, then is Nvidia's driver not broken? Nobody has noticed this until now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that this is only an issue with the default framebuffer, therefor it must be a bug in Nvidia's WGL implementation. I've pointed it out to them so hopefully it will be fixed.

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate a little more? I am also interested. How did you come up to this conclusion?

Answer (score 1):

With GLX (Linux), I experience the same behaviour as well. It will report linear despite it clearly rendering as sRGB. One way you can verify that it is in fact working is by using an sRGB texture with texel value 1, render this texture to your sRGB framebuffer and see that it shows a dark-grey square. (For comparison, you can see how it looks when the texture is not an sRGB texture - still with texel value 1, that should give a lighter-grey square).

You can see this example: https://github.com/julienaubert/glsrgb

Interestingly, with an OpenGL ES context, the (almost) same code does not render correctly.

There is a topic on nvidia's developer OpenGL forum:

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/776591/opengl/gl_framebuffer_srgb-functions-incorrectly/